how does a Sear Haack body and rotation interact
If a Sear Haack body is launched out at supersonic speeds and given a extremely high rotational speed will the Sear Haack body stay stable over a long distance or will it start to tumble and if it does fly with stability how dramatically is it affected by side winds. And does rotation effect the aerodynamics of the Sear Haack body in any way shape or form.

Quarterbacks in football may know the answer.

Well, all quarterbacks which throw at supersonic speeds that is...

OK, how about a rifle bullet
